# Having issue susing the MAX command in Databricks

Tags: sql, window-functions, azure-databricks

Just running a simple query

```
select COL1
from ( 
    select *
    , monotonically_increasing_id() as row_id 
    from db00sparkmigration_landingzone_template.tbl_Ingestion_note_load_errors_pipes 
    ) aa
where row_id > 1 and row_id < max(row_id)
```

but getting the following error, any ideas?

> Error in SQL statement: UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot evaluate expression: max(input[1, bigint, false])

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `row_number()` here - however you need a column that defines the ordering of the rows:

```
select col1
from ( 
    select 
        t.*,
        row_number() over(order by <ordering_col> asc)  rn_asc,
        row_number() over(order by <ordering_col> desc) rn_desc
    from db00sparkmigration_landingzone_template.tbl_Ingestion_note_load_errors_pipes t
) aa
where 1 not in (rn_asc, rn_desc)
```